# jquery mobile loadpage problem

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

I am trying to use loadPage with jquery mobile and the function doesn't seem to return data to the desired page container.

My javasript is like so

```
  $('.numMobi a').live("click", function() {  
        var dataurl = $(this).attr("data-url");  
        if (dataurl != null)  
            $.mobile.loadPage("lib/loadMobis.php",{
                pageContainer:$("#MobiDirSites"),
                data:dataurl, 
                transition: "slideup"
            }); 
    });
```

I get the databack in firebug but it is not inserting it in the page.

Here is my html

```
<div data-role="page" id="MobiDir">
    <div data-role="header" class="header" role="banner">
    </div>
    <div data-role="content" id="MobiDirSites"> 
    </div>
    <div data-role="footer">
    </div>
</div>
```

Any ides why it isn't inserting it?

Comment: Are you looking for changePage() instead? http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.0b1/#/demos/1.0b1/docs/api/methods.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In my test, your code successfully fetched the URL and loaded it into `#MobiDirSites`. I suspect this is what you want, since you're specifying a target element on the existing page. What I think Phill is picking up on is the fact that you specified a `transition` in your `loadPage()` call. `transition` only applies to `changePage()`.